# How to dynamically select option in dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

> How to do when selecting the one subject then the time will appear according to the subject selected? each subject have many options of time and how to display when select one subject and the time display the time selected subject

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"> Subject 1: </label> <font color="red"> * </font>
        <select id="levelSbj1" name="levelSbj1" class="form-control" required="required">
            <option value="0"> - Select Subject--</option>
            <option value="1"> Bahasa Malaysia</option>
            <option value="2"> English</option>
            <option value="3"> Mathematics</option>
            <option value="4"> Science</option>
        </select>
</div>
            
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"> Time and Day: </label> <font color="red"> * </font>
        <select id="levelLvl1" name="levelLvl1" class="form-control" required="required">
            <option value="0"> - Select Time and Day--</option>
            <option value="1"> 10.00 - 12.00 am (Saturday)</option>
            <option value="1"> 2.00 - 4.00 pm (Saturday)</option>
            <option value="2"> 9.00am - 11.00am (Friday)</option>
            <option value="2"> 3.00 - 5.00 pm (Friday)</option>
            <option value="3"> 10.00 - 12.00 am (monday)</option>
            <option value="3"> 2.00 - 4.00 pm (tuesday)</option>
            <option value="4"> 9.00 - 11.00 am (thursday)</option>
            <option value="4"> 3.00 - 5.00 pm (sunday)</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

Subject 1:   * 
        
             - Select Subject--
             Bahasa Malaysia
             English
             Mathematics
             Science

Time and Day:   * 
        
             - Select Time and Day--
             10.00 - 12.00 am (Saturday)
             2.00 - 4.00 pm (Saturday)
             9.00am - 11.00am (Friday)
             3.00 - 5.00 pm (Friday)
             10.00 - 12.00 am (monday)
             2.00 - 4.00 pm (tuesday)
             9.00 - 11.00 am (thursday)
             3.00 - 5.00 pm (sunday)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll probably have to write code to do that. When the Subject is selected, you can select the appropriate time in the Time and Day dropdown. Post your code if you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On client-side you can try with jQuery like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // when selection changes on Subject
  $('#levelSbj1').on('change', function(e) {
    var currentSubject = $(this);
    var timeSelect = $('#levelLvl1');
    // select time which corresponds to the subbject's value
    timeSelect.val(currentSubject.val());

    var resultsDiv = $('#result');

    switch (currentSubject.val()) {
      case '1': // Bahasa Malaysia
        resultsDiv.html('<span>Subject: ' + currentSubject.find("option:selected").text() + ', Time: ' + timeSelect.find('option').eq(1).text() + ' - ' + timeSelect.find('option').eq(2).text() + '</span>');
        break;
      case '2': // English
        resultsDiv.html('<span>Subject: ' + currentSubject.find("option:selected").text() + ', Time: ' + timeSelect.find('option').eq(1).text() + ' - ' + timeSelect.find('option').eq(3).text() + '</span>');
        break;
      case '3': // Mathematics
        resultsDiv.html('<span>Subject: ' + currentSubject.find("option:selected").text() + ', Time: ' + timeSelect.find('option').eq(3).text() + ' - ' + timeSelect.find('option').eq(4).text() + '</span>');
        break;
      case '4': // Science
        resultsDiv.html('<span>Subject: ' + currentSubject.find("option:selected").text() + ', Time: ' + timeSelect.find('option').eq(2).text() + ' - ' + timeSelect.find('option').eq(3).text() + '</span>');
        break;
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Subject 1:</label>
  <font color="red">*</font>
  <select id="levelSbj1" name="levelSbj1" class="form-control" required="required">
    <option value="0">--Select Subject--</option>
    <option value="1">Bahasa Malaysia</option>
    <option value="2">English</option>
    <option value="3">Mathematics</option>
    <option value="4">Science</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Time and Day:</label>
  <font color="red">*</font>
  <select id="levelLvl1" name="levelLvl1" class="form-control" required="required">
    <option value="0">--Select Time and Day--</option>
    <option value="1">10.00 - 12.00 am (Saturday)</option>
    <option value="2">2.00 - 4. 00 pm (Saturday)</option>
    <option value="3">9.00 - 11.00 am (Friday)</option>
    <option value="4">3.00 - 5. 00 pm (Friday)</option>
    <option value="5">10.00 - 12.00 am (monday)</option>
    <option value="6">2.00 - 4. 00 pm (tuesday)</option>
    <option value="7">9.00 - 11.00 am (thursday)</option>
    <option value="8">3.00 - 5. 00 pm (sunday)</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

**Update**

You cannot display more than one selected option in an HTML select, unless using multi-select like this: [enter link description here](https://html.com/attributes/select-multiple/)

You can, however, extract the values of multiple options and display them somewhere. I've updated the code snippet. Check it out to see how it's done. This is just a dummy example, you will need to adjust it according to your requirements.

Comment: what if I just want to display the selected time for the selected subject? for example, if I select subject English then there are displays 3 different time for the English subject.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include an example for your second question. I believe that both of your questions have been answered. If you have any further question that is different from current topic, I encourage you to open a new thread.